# CE/FCC/RoHS/etc certification for Intel NUC and other barebone MiniPCs?

Tags: fcc, certification, ce, rohs

Intel sell the Intel NUC without a hard drive or ram. They provide a list of compatible rams and drives. By sliding in the ram stick and drive, am I not invalidating all of the certificates on the bottom of the unit?

[image]

Comment: Would you invalidate the CE mark on audio equipment by pushing a CD into the player?

Comment: I don't know. But according to a CTO that flagged this and the COO that is looking into this, this invalidates the certification.

Comment: @Andyaka No, but putting random rams or drivers may violate CE marking

Answer (score 2):

The key is

> They provide a list of compatible rams and drives.

They are probably certifying the device with anything on that list; provided you insert something on that list, the certification remains valid.

They should make the relevant technical documentation (e.g. technical construction file, for CE compliance) certifying conformance available. Possibly on their website; certainly to reasonable requests for compliance information. Details of how they are claiming compliance should be in the documentation.

From a technical but not a legal standpoint; if you insert a similar device not on the list, the equipment is likely to comply with all relevant regulations but is no longer legally certified. Fine for your own use perhaps, but you would have to certify it yourself for re-sale.

If you insert something not similar (e.g. a drive with much higher power consumption) it may no longer comply (e.g. overheating). Then you are on your own.

Comment: Nice answer. Another obvious point: if you insert something not on the list it may no longer comply to the EMC directive. You have to validate that (yourself or by a test lab). If device A complies to EMC and device B as well, that does **not** guarantee the merging of these devices will be EMC